# Understanding Binding Context in Assemblies

Tags: .net, assemblies

I've been reading [Choosing Binding Context - Suzanne Cook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context.aspx) however I don't quite get it. Perhaps due to the fact that English is my second language but when she is talking about Contexts, it seems she is actually talking about where Load, LoadFrom, LoadFile are looking up to find assemblies. What is the context she is talking about? AppDomain or something else?

As long as I can reach them within the same AppDomain then what's the difference between them actually? All the difference so far looks where they seek out assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding context is actually more like an internal assembly cache which will be consulted the next time you ask for an assembly. So yes, it's basically has to do with resolving assemblies.

**Edit:**
So for each of these contexts there is a cache of assemblies references by their full name. The next time you ask for an assembly it will first look in this cache.

This means that for example an assembly in the Load-context (.NET framework), cannot load an assembly from the LoadFrom context.

**Sources:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/01/29/64265.aspx

http://www.techbubbles.com/net-framework/assembly-binding-in-net-framework/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727509.aspx#id0400031 **new**

Comment: Could you please give me a link or something where I read this with details?

Comment: I added some links, check out the last one first, it explains it a lot more detailed than the other ones I found.